# Java time Error converting data

Tags: java

I have a little problem with the translation of this data  **19/12/2005
17:30:45 to mileseconds**. I don't know why, I am getting a wrong translation to **Jun 28 17:30:45 CEST 1995 Time :804353445798**

The code I used is this :

```
private static long ConvertTimeToTimeStamp(String time) {   

  Integer[] data = new Integer[6];
  String [] tokens = time.split(" "); 

  System.out.println(tokens[0]);
  System.out.println(tokens[1]);

  String[] d_m_y = tokens[0].split("/"); 
  String[] hh_mm_ss = tokens[1].split(":"); 

  for (int i = 0; i < d_m_y.length; i++) {
    data[i]=Integer.parseInt(d_m_y[i]); 
    // System.out.println(d_m_y[i]);        
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < hh_mm_ss.length; i++) {
    data[i+3]=Integer.parseInt(hh_mm_ss[i]); 
    //  System.out.println(hh_mm_ss[i]);    
  }
  //Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance(); 
  GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); 
  calendar.set(data[0]+1970, data[1], data[2], data[3],data[4],data[5]);

  System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toString()); 
  return calendar.getTimeInMillis(); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should not parse the date manually - use a [date format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead:

```
String s = "19/12/2005 17:30:45";
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Treat this object from the outset as a date. That will be *much* more reliable.

Use [SimpleDateFormat.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) to parse your string into a date/time. Otherwise you're reduced to string parsing/splitting/recombining etc with no bounds-checking, type-checking etc. Your solution is *stringly*-typed, not *strongly*-typed.

I've referenced the standard Java libraries, but [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is a better bet for doing date work in Java and I would advise adopting this for a more intuitive and safer API.

Comment: 'stringly-typed'? You sir, get a cookie!

Answer (score 1):

Forget about it. Use a `SimpleDataFormat` object with pattern `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` to `parse()` the String into a date object.

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
private static long ConvertTimeToTimeStamp(String time) { 
   //19/12/2005 17:30:45
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
   java.util.Date d = sdf.parse(time);
   return d.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the order of year, month and day. The `set` method is expecting them in the following order: year, month, day and you are providing them as `day + 1970`, `month`, `year`.
Having said that, you might actually be much more happy with a library like [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).